# cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE doesn't simplify the number of contour points for a rectangle

Tags: python, opencv

I'm basically following [this python OpenCV contour guide](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html).
I'm using `OpenCV 2.4.11` installed through `Brew` (OSX).

Everything appears to basically work, other than when I do:
`contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

I get the same number of contour coordinate points as with `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`.

So in the example of the link, I still get `734` points rather than `4`.

Anyone else experienced this?

NB: (Note that `cv2.findContours` returns `contours, hierarchy` contrary to the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation, what appears to be happening here is many contours being drawn over each other (hiding the fact that `APPROX_SIMPLE` is in fact working).

Notice this by seeing that there are the same number of contours, but that the number of points in each contour changes (goes down with the above option).